# Blank but still somewhat working user interface

Tags: java, swing, centos

I've written a Java database program using Swing, and it looks and works fine on my Windows machine. I was expecting to be able to transfer it to my Linux (CentOS 6) machine with no problems, and while it compiles and runs just fine, the GUI is blank.

Specifically, a `JDialog` that I show appears as a solid grey rectangle, but I can still see my cursor change to an `I` bar when I hover over the text boxes, and I can type into them and press the invisible Ok button, and it works. (This is a database login dialog.)

Then, a `JFrame` that I've setup as an MDI parent is displayed, but it has zero size. If I drag it open it does have a border, but it does not visibly have the menu that I placed on it. I don't seem to be able to access the menu invisibly as I was able to on the JDialog.

I suspect that this must have something to do with some Java or library version, but I'm not sure. I tried installing Java 7 but it didn't change anything. I'm not sure if I should uninstall Java completely and try reinstalling it, or if maybe it has something to do with the project instead (I am using Eclipse Kepler if that helps.)

I see a few other "Java program is blank" questions, but they either do not have answers or are not the same issue I am having. (My program is only blank under CentOS so far; it works and looks just fine under Windows.)

Comment: Can we see some code related with JDialog or JFrame?

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you call `setVisible` before you finished building the UI, but it could also be a driver issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed it down to a single line. In the `JDialog` I had the following:

```
setType(Type.POPUP);
```

as soon as I removed this line, the dialog became visible.

Additionally, I find that if I use the `Test/Preview...` feature (this is using the WindowBuilder) when that line is present, it shows the dialog blank, but it is non-interactive and effectively hangs Eclipse. This led me to "end-task" java.exe, which did unfreeze Eclipse, but it ended up causing even more problems, including the ones I was having with my MDI `JFrame`.

After rebooting, and removing the above `POPUP` line, everything is working great.